# Load iframe after authentication

Tags: php, curl, facebook-apps

I am looking for a secure solution for this particular scenario :

1. I have an index.php file (let's say www.my-app.com/index.php)
2. I have to HTTP Post the authentication details to www.domain.com/login
3. When login is verified, I have to load the response in an iframe within the index.php

while researching I found the following solutions,

> Solution #1: Use javascript(jquery) / simple html form to submit
>   username & password to www.domain.com and mention the target as id of
>   that particular iframe. Thus the application loads in that iframe.

My take : This may not be secure as username and password may be sniffed, session may be hijacked. I have no idea how, but it seems to be possible. ( Even hidden variables can be seen in source )

Solution #2:

> Use php curl to submit the username & password and load the url in the
>   iframe.

(Not very clear how to implement this. )

Limitations : Not an expert in php (obvious I suppose ). A code snippet would help.

Is there another way to implement the same technique in a secure way?

I have seen facebook do the same with their Page Tab Applications. I am sure most of the payment frameworks do the same. But how are they doing it ?

Comment: I guess a little more clarity on why I am doing/want this is required! The Customer has his website at my-app.com. He is using our application at domain.com to show in an iframe on his page. Now our application can have any number of customers. What we want is that he is authenticated so that we can identify him and our application loads only those services/information that are relevant to him or belong to him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have much knowledge on CURL.It may help you for your second solution (PHP - CURL )

```
<?php
 $ch = curl_init('http://mysite.com/index.php');
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=xyz&pwd=123");
 $result = curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

As per php manual :

```
  curl_exec() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. 
  However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.
```

So you have the result from the other site which you can display in `iframe`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I shall try this out.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to HTTP Post the authentication details to www.domain.com/login

From your security concerns I gather that these authentication details are not those of the current user of your app, but general auth details required to access the services of domain.com using a fixed account belonging to you?

If so, I’d say that’s *broken by design*. You can not have a client login to some other service with *your* login credentials in any save manner.

If that service on domain.com is your own, you have to think of something else to authenticate a client with it without having to give the login credentials to that client.

If it’s a third party service you’re using – ask them to provide some better solution.

And btw., what exactly does this have to do with Facebook?

Comment: Facebook Page Tab Apps work like this - We have a server that is hosting the app at domain.com/pagetabapp. Whenever a facebook user visits our app on the business page, FB posts certain information to our server. We then process it and redirect it to the application url. Then our application is loaded on an iFrame on the business page.

Comment: You don’t have to explain to me how page tab apps in general work :-) Still don’t see your problem, though …

Comment: Do you have an idea how they would have implemented it ?

Comment: Implement what? I still can’t see where you want to sent any login data, and what your actual security concerns about this are.

Comment: I was talking about the implementation of the Facebook Page Tab. How do you think they would have implemented it ?